# What's your favorite SOFU question of 2009?

Tags: discussion, polling

There are so many questions, especially on SO, that I know I see only a small fraction.  In the spirit of "Best of ..." lists that usually come out at the start of a new year, I'd like to collect a set of questions that the community thought were the "Best of 2009" across the SO family of sites.  As a benefit we'll collect in a single place a set of questions that you may have missed that others found to be valuable.

The way it works:  Add an answer to this question indicating your favorite question **asked in 2009**.  Link to the question and add a short description of why it's your favorite.  To increase the value of the list, please limit your submissions to questions that materially affected the way you work.  **One question per answer, please.**

I found viewing favorites ordered by newest was helpful to me in coming up with my entry.

Answer (score 9):

Someone has to do it, so it might as well be me:

**[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)**

Just for [bobince's legendary answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: All non-surpassable awesomeness of that answer aside -- I don't believe you that this question (or the answer) *materially affected the way you work.*

Comment: @balpha that's debatable. It reinforced my view that regex is more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: No one will drive us from the paradise which <del>Cantor</del> bobince created for us.

Answer (score 2):

[Objective-C @class vs. #import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322597/objective-c-class-vs-import)

It's actually a fairly basic question, but it's a serious point of confusion for many newcomers to Objective-C (and thus Cocoa, and Mac or iPhone) development. Indeed, it was a major point of confusion for me when I was just starting out, and the accepted answer to this question was in fact what finally got it to "sink in" to my thick skull.

I should note that this one hasn't improved my "daily" work, as I'm primarily a .NET guy. But I'm also a die-hard Mac fanboy, and thus my personal fun software development is all Cocoa/Obj-C -- and this was again a major stumbling block for me early on.

Answer (score 1):

[LINQ to SQL extension method for sorting and paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543955/linq-to-sql-extension-method-for-sorting-and-paging).

This question and the resulting link to Scott Guthrie's article on Dynamic LINQ was, I think, my first exposure to Dynamic LINQ.  I've found Dynamic LINQ to be extremely useful in my work.  It also gave me a lot of ideas that I've used in my own paging implementations in LINQ.